# Se puede modificar un elemento de Boton a Input Text con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Se puede modificar el elemento, del DOM con jQuery.
Es decir declararlo como Boton y luego con jQuery convertirlo en text.
o cuando tengo una tabla con registros nose darle doble click a un td se convierta en un input text donde yo pueda modificar?
Estuve provando con `attr` o `prop`, nose si yo estoy mal o esque no se puede

```js
$('button').dblclick(function() {
    editar();
});

function editar(){
  $('button').attr("type", 'input');
  console.log('Estas adentro');
}

 $('#tabla tbody tr > td').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    //$(elemento).prop("button");
    //$(this).html("Hola");
    console.log($(this).html());
    editar();
    //alert();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toca me dos veces seguido</button><br>
<table id="tabla" border=1>
<tr>MI NOMBRE COMPLETO</tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer solo se puede cuando el botón es un elemento `input`, de lo contrario seguirá siendo botón, otra posible solución es eliminar el botón y agregar un `input` con las características que tenia el botón eliminado

Tu código modificado, el botón es un `input` y no un `button`

ahora para las tablas solo hay que agregar el atributo `contentEditable` y ya no seria necesario llamar al método `editar()`

```js
$('input[type="button"]').dblclick(function() {
    editar();
});

function editar(){
  $('input[type="button"]').attr("type", 'text');
  console.log('Estas adentro');
}

 $('#tabla tbody tr > td').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red').attr('contentEditable',true);
    //$(elemento).prop("button");
    //$(this).html("Hola");
    console.log($(this).html());
    //editar();
    //alert();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Toca me dos veces seguido"><br>
<table id="tabla" border=1>
<tr>MI NOMBRE COMPLETO</tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Ivan</td>
<td>Joel</td>
<td>More</td>
<td>Flores</td>
</table>
```

Comment: y como seria en el caso de la tabla?

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores he agregado la modificación a la tabla

Comment: Muchas gracias (Y)